# Show that $E =\{(x,\alpha )\mid|f(x)|>\alpha\geq 0 \}$ is measurable.

Tags: proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

> Show that $E=\{(x,\alpha )\mid|f(x)|>\alpha\geq 0 \}$ is measurable, where $f$ is integrable.

Is my proof correct?

Let $A$ measurable and $f=1_A$. Then $E=A\times [0,1]$ which is measurable.

If $f=\sum \limits _{i=1}^n a_i 1_{A_i}$ is simple, then $E=\bigcup \limits _{i=1}^n A_i\times [0,a_i]$ which is measurable. If $f\geq 0$, there is an increasing sequence $(f_n)$ of simple function s.t. $f_n\to f$.

If I denote $E^n=\{x\mid |f_n(x)|>\alpha \geq 0\}$ then $E^n\subset E^{n+1}$ and $E=\bigcup \limits _{n=1}^\infty E^n$. Since $E$ are measurable and the union is countable, then $E$ is measurable. If $f$ is measurable, then we can take a sequence $|f_n|\to |f|$ of simple function that is increasing and do as we did previously.

Comment: Too sloppy to examine properly! You forgot to mention in your question that $f$ is a measurable function. The notation $E_{\alpha}$ suggests that $\alpha$ is fixed, so that for e.g. $f=1_A$ and $0<\alpha<1$ we have $E_{\alpha}=A\times\{\alpha\}$. Then suddenly $x$ appears as index in $E_{x,\alpha}$. First repair some things.

Comment: is it better now ? @drhab

Comment: Yes, it is better. But not good enough. I will have a second look after some time.

Comment: $x,\alpha$ are used as indices (**fixed**) and **variables** in the same definition. That makes no sense. They are not functional as indices and you can just speak of the set $E$ instead of $E_{x,\alpha}$ or $E_{\alpha}$. After removing them the spot is free and you can write $E_n$ instead of $E^n$.

Comment: You are right. I corrected it. Sorry for that. Is it clear now ? @drhab

Comment: No. Is $f$ a function $X\to\mathbb R$ where $\langle X,\mathcal A\rangle$ is some mearable space? Is $E$ a subset of $\mathbb R^2$? Is it to be shown that $E$ is an element of the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^2$ and in that sense a measurable set? It smells like that, but these are all things that must be given by the person who asks the question, and not the person who is willing to answer it. Btw, if $f=1_A$ then $E\neq A\times[0,1]$. If e.g. $\alpha=1$ then there is no $x$ with $f(x)=1_A(x)>1$.

Comment: My exercise is exactly as it's written (I correct measurable as integrable). So is $E=A\times [0,1[$ ?

Comment: Ok, I erased it. Sorry for all these mistakes. So does $E=A\times [0,1)$ (if $f=1_A$) ? I just need to know if this is correct, for the rest I think it is correct if $E=A\times [0,1)$ in the case where $f=1_A$. Thanks. @drhab

Comment: I am glad someone has answered your question allready.

Answer (score 1):

If $f=1_A$, then $E=\{(x,\alpha )\in A\times \mathbb R \mid 0\leq \alpha <1\}=A\times [0,1)$. Same with $f$ simple. Otherwise your proof is perfectly correct.